# IntelliJ 2017.2 cursor is freezing temporarily when traversing through VCS Dialog or Project View

Tags: intellij-idea

After I updated from 2017.**1** to 2017.**2** my cursor navigation outside the editor is lagging.

Examples are the project view and the VSC Dialog (log, local changes aka changelists, etc.)

When I traverse with my cursor from top to bottom and back the cursor sometimes stops and nothing happens. When I wait some time it is movable again.

Funny thing is that IntelliJ itself does not seem to be freezing - it's just the cursor movement that stops.
That is because I'm able to click with my mouse anything in the list I'm traversing through, even when the cursor is freezing again I am always able to at least click the desired field/option.

I'd love to provide some kind of detail log but am not able to find any.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems